# Stop command without pressing Ctrl+C (No luck using trap function)

Tags: linux, command-line

I am trying to make a script that runs 2 commands in a for loop as can be seen below:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=0; i<2; i++)); do
    sudo ./bin/llc test-rx -c 184 
    sleep 5
    trap ctrl_c INT
function ctrl_c() 
{
  echo "Trap: CTRL+C received, exit"
  exit
}
    sudo ./bin/llc rxphylast  
done
```

The 1st command (test-rx) continues to run as its is executed and it is stopped by pressing Ctrl+C. I want to stop this command in bash script so I used trap function as can be seen in the code. But when I execute the script, 1st command is running until I press Ctrl+C and then 2nd command (rxphylast) executes. So, in my case trap function is not working. Any advice on how to stop the 1st command in the script?

Answer (score 1):

1. Define the function and set the trap outside of the loop
2. Define the function before you use it.

Try:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
function ctrl_c() (

{
  echo "Trap: CTRL+C received, exit"
  exit
}

trap ctrl_c INT

for ((i=0; i<2; i++)); do
    sudo ./bin/llc test-rx -c 184 
    sleep 5

    sudo ./bin/llc rxphylast  
done
```

Another example, not using ./bin/llc:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function ctrl_c()
{
  echo "Trap: CTRL+C received, exit"
  exit
}

trap ctrl_c INT

for ((i=0; i<2; i++)); do
    echo first program
    sudo find / -type f > /dev/null
    sleep 5

    echo second program
    sudo find / -type f > /dev/null
done
```

Press Ctrl-C while the first `find` is running and it will print the "Trap: CTRL+C received, exit" message and exit immediately.  Press Ctrl-C while the second `find` is running and it will do the same.  This works the same whether `sudo` is used with the find commands or not - I only put that in there to make sure it wasn't sudo trapping and eating the Ctrl-C.

This is what happens when you run it and press Ctrl-C while the first find is running:

```bash
$ ./trap.sh 
first program
^CTrap: CTRL+C received, exit
$
```

Comment: Well, it didn't work. Its the same I have to stop by using Ctrl+C

Comment: does `./bin/llc` also trap SIGINT?  The script works exactly as expected if i use other programs (like `find / > /dev/null`, I tested this with and without `sudo`)  instead of llc.

Comment: I had to use ./bin/llc otherwise the commands test-rx and rxphylast will not work. Could u send me ur code with other programs?

Comment: Hi Cas, I tried the new program code that u wrote. Its working fine. ./bin is the location where llc shared library is present and using this llc i can use various commands like test-rx, rxphylast etc. May be its the issue of path ./bin/llc

Comment: It's not (and can't be) the path `./bin`.  It might be the program `llc`.  All evidence so far points to that.

Comment: Hi Cas. Can I use kill command to stop the process? I used it and I want to show the code. Where should I post? As I posted in the answer but it got deleted by the admin. I am new here so that's why asking

Comment: I don't see why not, but if you're talking about running kill inside the loop after sleeping for a few seconds (as in your deleted post), I also don't see the point.   Why not just fix whatever `./bin/llc test-rx -c 184` is doing so that it a) doesn't run forever and/or b) doesn't swallow SIGINT?   It seems to me like you're trying to solve the wrong problem.   What is it that you're actually trying to do?